# Why can't I redirect to the file that grep uses for input?

Tags: bash, grep, io-redirection

```
File1:
foo
bar
baz

File2:
bar.patch

grep -f file1 file2 > file1
```

Expected result, file1 contains bar.patch, instead it is empty.

How is grep processing the input file such that I cannot redirect to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection `>` happens before the command is executed, hence the grep sees empty file and returns nothing. If you really want to write to the same file you can use the [`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) command (it is part of the moreutils). It buffers the input and writes to the output file only after the end of data. Example:

```
grep -f file1 file2 | sponge file1
```

Check the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) for details about redirection:

> **Before a command is executed**, its input and output may be redirected
> using a special notation interpreted by the shell. Redirection allows
> commands’ file handles to be duplicated, opened, closed, made to refer
> to different files, and can change the files the command reads from
> and writes to. Redirection may also be used to modify file handles in
> the current shell execution environment. The following redirection
> operators may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or
> may follow a command. Redirections are processed in the order they
> appear, from left to right.

Or just redirect to a temporary file and then `mv` it over the `file1`.

```
grep -f file1 file2 > file3
mv -f file3 file1
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that `tee` won't open `file1` for writing (thus truncating it) before `grep` has finished reading git. It's just as bad as the output redirection. `sponge` or the temporary file is necessary.

Comment: Oh, right, `sponge` is only buffering the output of `grep`, not affecting what `tee` does to `file1`.

Comment: _nod_. `grep -f file1 file2 | sponge file1` is fine. `grep -f file1 file2 | sponge | tee file1` is not.

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked the parallel execution of the pipe. Good points.